Gradle Jacoco failing with java 17
I am using gradle and Jacoco for my spring boot project. Unfortunately, my tests were not running and getting below exception. My gradle version https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.8-bin.zip
jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.11"
}
java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}
test {
systemProperty "Log4jContextSelector", "org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.BasicContextSelector"

jacoco {
    destinationFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/jacocoTest.exec")
    classDumpDir = file("$buildDir/jacoco/classpathdumps")
   }
}

jacocoTestReport {
reports {
    html.required.set(true)
}
afterEvaluate {
    classDirectories.setFrom(files(classDirectories.files.collect {
        fileTree(dir: it, exclude: [ '**/config/*', '**/models/*', '**/*Application*' ])
    }))
   }
}


 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:491)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:503)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Class java/util/UUID could not be instrumented.
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_e5875b2.core.runtime.ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.createFor(ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.java:140)
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_e5875b2.core.runtime.ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.createFor(ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.java:101)
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_e5875b2.PreMain.createRuntime(PreMain.java:55)
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_e5875b2.PreMain.premain(PreMain.java:47)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: $jacocoAccess
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getField(Class.java:2117)
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_e5875b2.core.runtime.ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.createFor(ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.java:138)
    ... 9 more
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: 

I have searched lot of other posts and could figure out what is causing this.

I have resolved the issue by deleting older Jacoco agent dependency locked with below version in my global.lock file. I have removed them and it stated working straight away.
    "jacocoAgent": {
    "org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent": {
        "locked": "0.7.8"
    }
},
"jacocoAnt": {
    "org.jacoco:org.jacoco.ant": {
        "locked": "0.7.8"
    }
},

